# Merging nested folders

Tags: files, backup, directory, merge

My first posting here. Even though it may seem like a common question, I've searched the entire forums and still couldn't find a solution to this specific problem. So I decided to ask.

I'm having a lot of trouble solving a backup problem. I need to merge several enclosed and non enclosed folders, each to its own (slightly different) copy.

Let me explain. I've created several copies of my hard drive along some period of time which were functioning as backups. The problem is that these weren't incremental backups. As crazy as it may sound, these were actual copies of the whole folders/files, stored in an external drive as "backupFeb2015", "backupNov2015", "backupJan2016" and so on.

(I had a reason to do that, but explaining this here would take long and is not important)

In each of these "backupMMMYYYY" I have several other folders, like Pics, Docs etc.

Inside Pics, for instance, I may have "TripToXPlace", "TripToYPlace" etc. You get the idea.

I'd like to be able to simply do something like copy "backupNov2015" into "backupFeb2015" and have them both merged, that is, each thing in its folder of the same name (backupNov2015's TripToXPlace would be copied into backupFeb2015's TripToXPlace) and everything gets merged in order to have them all together and still avoid both duplicating or losing new files that were added to the folders through time.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Wouldn't your most recent backup be enough? Doesn't it include all the files?

Comment: That's the worst part. It isn't. I've made many mistakes in my life, and this one of the important ones... lol
I used a program to delete duplicates, but then I realized it wouldn't have sort of a main folder according to which all the others would be evaluated. Now there are files in one which are not in the other similar folder. I'm almost doing this by hand, but it will take days.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this: take the OLDEST backup folder and rename from "backupFeb2015" (or what it would be) to "restore" or any other name you would like. Copy to a new location or few levels up. Then go back to the source location, rename the "restore" folder back to "backupFeb2015" and rename the next one "backupNov2015" to "restore". Copy and paste it to the destination location containing your restore. This way the copy operation detects the folder with the same name and you can now choose "merge folders" or something like that. choose the "do this to all files" or something and proceed. It will ask this for files too.  Do this until you had all backup folders and you should have all merged in your new folder. The old ones are still there, so you will not loose anything. GOOD LUCK

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It worked. Still a lot of work, as I'm having to go check inside each folder when the names don't match exactly. Good to make me learn to be more organized with my stuff.